# Group and count by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named transaction which holds bookings. The columns are transaction_id, username and date(timestamp).

I want to retrieve bookings for the username on each day for a week from current day like date, count for that date.

Comment: What have you tried? [SO] is not a code writing service, but we will help you when you get stuck: but you need to show what you have done.

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried with sample data and expected output.

Comment: i m new and query is complex thats y asked

Comment: i ll provide in some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this

```
select username,date,count(*) from table
where date>=date_add(current_date, interval -7 day)
group by username,date
```

Comment: thats it helped me start now this is query and its working `select created_at,count(*) from TRANSACTION
where created_at>=date_add(current_date, interval -7 day) and seller_id=2
group by created_at`

Comment: but it is giving for last 7 days i want for each day for seller_id 2

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
SELECT DATE(`date`) as dt, user_name, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM table
WHERE `date` > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY 1, 2
```